# Djinni make error

Tags: xcode7, djinni

stuck here on this make problem for djinni, everything is working and i am happy but for some reason I can't get djinni to generate proper files. When I build it fails and I can't get the .o object it's missing. Below are the logs, please help would appreciate help on this.

./run_djinni.sh
Already up to date: Djinni
Parsing...
Resolving...
Generating...
Copying generated code to final directories...
djinni completed.
deps/gyp/gyp amr.gyp -DOS=ios --depth=. -f xcode --generator-output=./build_ios -Icommon.gypi
xcodebuild -project build_ios/amr.xcodeproj -configuration Release -target amr_objc | xcpretty -c
▸ Building amr/libamr_objc [Release]
▸ Check Dependencies
▸ Compiling amrApi.mm
▸ Compiling MerchantObjc.mm
▸ Compiling amr.mm
▸ Compiling amrItem.mm
▸ Compiling amrHttpResponse.mm
▸ Compiling amrItem+Private.mm
▸ Compiling NetworkObjc.mm
▸ Compiling amrHttpResponse+Private.mm
** BUILD FAILED **

The following build commands failed:
    CompileC build/amr.build/Release-iphoneos/libamr_objc.build/Objects-normal/armv7/MerchantObjc.o objc/MerchantObjc.mm normal armv7 objective-c++ com.apple.compilers.llvm.clang.1_0.compiler
(1 failure)

Comment: As with your other similar question, the xcpretty output you're including here indicates which command failed, but doesn't indicate why.  It'll require more output to debug.

Comment: thank you, i will investigate further and provide logs.. we are moving away from this issue so now i can work on background, but would really appreciate some help with this :)